# Any way to establish 2-way syncing between Access and Excel with or without VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to manipulate imported data from Access in Excel and send back additional data to Access mdb database. Is this feasible?

Comment: The answer would be yes, but how much time are you willing to give to the issue, and what have you tried? [ask]

Comment: As I mentioned below the plan is to use DAO/ADO in VBA + some SQL statements if necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a place to start, you can:

```
1. Record a Macro
2. Do one manual import and manipulation
3. Stop the recording
```

and basically there you have the fundamentals of the code you need to do the rest.

Comment: Excel does not support export to Access (at least without VBA), only import is available!

Comment: Fair enough. And after step 3 from the above suggested starting place, you can look to append your Macro created VBA code with the code found at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11334263/1851961 . Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft office provide these two database management system access and excel both plays the vital role in database. Yes, you can easily import the access in excel without any VBA code with same database.

By reading the article I got the answer of the following query and easily http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Access-To-Excel-Converter-00660936

import the data into excel sheet.
You just have to read the article.

Comment: i'm aware of import functionality in excel from access database. I need reliable and fast technology to put data back to Access from Excel. I'm thinking of DAO right now.