# Excel Range into Existing Access Table

Tags: vb6, excel-2010, ado

I have a VB6 application in which I need to insert row/columns of data from an excel file into an access database.

My connection string for the access database:

```
db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\db.mdb" & ";Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=*****"
```

I am trying to insert data using this SQL string:

```
Dim sql As String
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_trade_tcp ("
sql = sql & "[field_A], "
sql = sql & "[field_B], "
sql = sql & "[field_C]"
sql = sql & ") "
sql = sql & "SELECT * FROM [Excel " & xlApp.Application.Version & ";HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Database=" & wb.FullName & "].[" & ws.Name & "$AH3:AJ36,B3:AG36]"

db.Execute sql
```

The problem now is keep getting this error message:

```
Cannot find installable ISAM
```

For reference purposes, there are the info that I used to create the sql string:

[Fastest way to copy an Excel range to Access?](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/microsoft-access/583521-fastest-way-copy-excel-range-access-2.html)

[Using Excel VBA to Export data to Ms.Access Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161865/using-excel-vba-to-export-data-to-ms-access-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into various posts, I have found out the following:

1. Instead of using the current machines' Excel Version, one needs to default to Excel 8.0

   SELECT * FROM [**Excel " & xlApp.Application.Version & "**;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Database=" & wb.FullName & "].[" & ws.Name & "$AH3:AJ36,B3:AG36]"

   should be

   SELECT * FROM [**Excel 8.0**;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;Database=" & wb.FullName & "].[" & ws.Name & "$AH3:AJ36,B3:AG36]"

   Reference: [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/sharepoint-blog/could-not-find-installable-isam-17062)
2. Be sure that columns names matches from the excel file.  If there are no column names in the excel file, then you need to declare them one by one.

   Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333865/export-data-from-excel-to-access-error-argument-not-optional)